# How did English get the "What is your name?" construction?

Tags: etymology, phrases, history

As a dabbling polyglot, I've found myself learning the basics of several languages over the course of my lifetime.  One of the first things that is taught in any language is personal introductions.  I was struck recently by the fact that English is the only language I have learned that uses the construction

> What is your name?

Spanish, French, Italian, German, and Chinese all use some variation of

> How are you called?

I'm told that Russian has something approximating "What is your name?" but it is sounds archaic to use it.  The modern version is closer to "What are you called?"

So I'm curious.  How did English end up with a phrase that is so different than the rest?

N.B. I am not interested in opening a can of worms regarding social conventions.  Regardless of how blunt we may consider the use of "What is your name?" in a social context, English speakers would find it exceedingly odd to use "How are you called?" in its place.  If it helps, let's forget the introductory aspect, and think of "What is *his* name?" versus "How is *he* called?"

**UPDATE:**  So far it looks like Old and Middle English used a phrase similar to German and Scandinavian countries.  Monica Cellio says that Modern Hebrew has this "What is your name" construction as well.  Is there any evidence that this new phrasing might have been picked up in Early Modern English, perhaps after the introduction of the King James Version of the Bible?

Comment: As far as I know, in formal speech English also tend to something like *How should/can I call/address you*.

Comment: I don't really see how this question can be explored *without* mostly talking about social conventions. People's names are powerful things, and the way any particular language handles things in that area is likely to be circumspect, to say the least.

Comment: It may be unusual but it's not unique to English; modern Hebrew also uses "what is [your, his, etc] name?".  (Biblical Hebrew often has the "called" construction.)

Comment: I am not interested in opening a can of worms regarding social conventions. If a friend tells me she went on a date with a new guy, I would say "What is his name?" not "How is he called?" nor "How do you address him?" nor "What should I call him?"

Comment: @Monica Cellio Do you think we got this convention from modern Hebrew? Or that they are related somehow?

Comment: Dutch and German have a special verb for this, *heten* and *heißen*, respectively. You could translate them as "be named/called", but that's really a different construction. Dutch: *Hoe heet je? / Wie ben je? Wat is je naam [this is an emphatic question]? — Ik heet / ik ben / mijn naam is Cerberus.*

Comment: @Cerberus: The same word exists in Swedish; *heta*, *Vad heter du?* - *Jag heter Göran*. Simliar in Norwegian and Danish, and probably Icelandic.

Comment: I wonder if it is really that different.

After all, the **name** is that by which something or someone is **called**, and the two phrases have the same meaning.

There are languages that follow one pattern or another (with variations, such as 'how do you call yourself?' and so on). Also, note swiss German might say: "Wie isch ire Name?"

Also, from etymology of [call][1] we have a meaning "to give a name to" is (from) mid-13c in English.

The word name, comes from Old English nama. Meaning "one's reputation" is from c.1300.

Comment: @Unreason That sounds like the makings of an interesting answer... *nudge, nudge*

Comment: @Monica Cellio as a Hebrew speaker I find it a lot more popular to say "How are you called" (איך קוראים לך) than "What's your name" (מה השם שלך / מה שמך). Actually the "What's your name" phrase is more official and/or archaic.

Comment: @Kit, I was actually writing it as an answer, but pushed it into a comment as I really don't offer an answer (not even a strong opinion on it); still per your nudge I did move it down (with just another small detail added to it).

Comment: @yellowblood, thanks for the information.  We were taught מה שמך in my Hebrew classes, but as we've seen on this site, how languages are taught as second languages doesn't always match what people do. :-)

Comment: @Kit, see @yellowblood's comment about Hebrew; my perspective may be skewed.  I don't know of a path between English and Hebrew (in either direction) that neatly lines up time-wise; I suspect the paths are independent.  But I'm not a language historian and could well be wrong.

Comment: @Kit. As a native speaker of Spanish, I'd say that "¿Cuál es tu nombre?" is pretty common and by no means archaic or contrived (it traslates literally as "*which* is your name", so the structure is almost identical to its English counterpart).

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano Thanks for the native speaker perspective. Looks like my elementary Spanish was about as accurate as @Monica's elementary Hebrew.

Comment: @Kit. No problem. I didn't mention it in the previous comment, but you are of course right in that "How are you called?" / "¿Cómo te llamas?" is also proper and common Spanish. Unfortunately, I don't have much to add about the English construction, which is obviously the main issue of your question.

Comment: I second @yellowblood's comment. As a child, I was taught the 'name' convention (I find that young children are often taught 'correct', if not slightly outdated Hebrew, and grow out of it into more acceptable slang), but I find the 'called' convention just as acceptable. Interestingly, as someone who's used both conventions, I think that 'called' is more fitting when talking to or about someone within your line of sight or in the current context, and 'name' is more fitting when talking about someone who is not present. Just my opinion, of course.

Comment: Years late, but the question was just pushed to the top. I can add that in all the Scandinavian languages, it is also perfectly normal to ask “What is your name?” rather than “How are you called?”. There is a slight difference in register, but it is not really one of formal vs. informal; rather, what matters is whether you are asking in order to know someone’s name and have a conversation with them, or simply in order to gather information (for filling out a form, say). There’s a lot of overlap, of course.

Comment: And also, for the record, the standard Chinese phrasing is 您贵姓？ _Nín guì xìng?_ (formal) / 你叫什么名字？ _Nǐ jiào shénme míngzi?_ (informal). Both use simplex verbs ‘to be called’, but one (姓 _xìng_) refers to one’s family name while the other (叫 _jiào_, lit. ‘call’) refers either to one’s full name or one’s given name(s) alone. In the informal version, the verb has an object ‘name’, so the phrase is really “What name are you called?”, a kind of portmanteau of the two constructions.

Comment: My recollection from Spanish class (about 50 years ago) is that the Spanish equivalent of "What are you called?" is, in effect, asking for your "everyday" name or nickname, while the Spanish "What is your name?" is asking for your formal name.  English does not make such a distinction.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are some reasons to believe that this peculiarity of today's English can be ascribed to the influence of Celtic Languages with which English has been in contact for the last 1500 years.

**Celtic influence**

Here are a few examples:

- In **Scottish Gaelic**, you ask someone’s name by saying “*Dè an t-ainm a tha ort?*”, literally “*What’s the name that's on you?*”.
- In **Irish** it would be “*Cad is ainm duit?*” (formal) – “*What name do you do?*”.
- Or informally, in Irish again, “*Cén t-ainm atá ort?*”, lit. “*What's the name on you?*”.
- In **Breton** (of France) “*Petra eo da anv?*”, lit. “*What is your name?*”.
- **Cornish** “*Puth yw dha hanow?*”, “*What is your name?*”.
- **Welsh** (formal): “*Beth ydych enw chi?*”, “*What is name you?*”.
- Welsh (informal), “*Beth ydy dy enw di?*”, “*What is your name from?*”.
- Welsh (informal), “*Beth yw dy enw?*”, “*What is your name?*”.

**General Celtic Influence**

Several linguists including J R R Tolkien have claimed that there is a British Isles *Sprachbund* incorporating English and the Celtic languages. 
For instance the “*I am working*”, “*I was working*” is common in Welsh and Irish, but you can’t say “*Ich bin arbeitend*” in German.
See the book "[The Celtic Roots of English](http://www.worldcat.org/title/celtic-roots-of-english/)" for more of these.

**The Old English way of asking "what's you name" was Germanic**

If you had a kind of Rosetta Stone handbook to learn Old English what would you find?  Well there are actually a few ones on the net.  [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/NiwEnglisc/Level_I/Hu_hattest_%C3%BEu%3F) is one.  And what do you think the title for the first question is?  Sure enough: “Hu hattest þu?”. Literally "*How call you*" (In German the verb *heißen* can be both intransitive "Wie heißt du?", or transitive).
So indeed when the Saxons and the Angles landed in the south East of the British Isles they still used the Germanic construction, which other answers and comments have shown, is still in use today in many Germanic languages.
For instance, out of [91 riddles](http://www2.kenyon.edu/AngloSaxonRiddles/texts.htm) in the 10th century [codex Exoniensis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exeter_Book), I've counted 13 occurrences of “Saga hwæt ic hatte” (“Say how I[am] called”) and 5 “Frige hwæt ic hatte” (“Guess how I [am] called”).

**When did it all change ?**

This is trickier but it is supposed to be during Middle English, the period between 1066 and 1450.
I'd like to cite two excerpts of the book *Beginning Old
 English*
 (Carole Hough and John Corbett
).

1. The *harrying of the north*: The Norman French, themselves descendants of Vikings, led by William the Conqueror, over-ran the Anglo-Saxon kingdoms and extended their territory throughout the Danelaw as far as the northern kingdom of Scotland.

   > In their vicious land-grab the Normans depopulated whole areas of Northumbria, carrying out an ethnic displacement later called ‘the harrying of the north’. Refugees from the defeated Anglo-Saxon dynasty fled with their retainers and servants to the court of the Celtic-speaking Scots in Edinburgh. There the Anglo-Saxon Princess Margaret married the widower King Malcolm. The speech of Queen Margaret and the Northumbrian refugees would eventually spread out over the Scottish lowlands, and become the basis of the lowland
   >   Scots tongue.
2. And a similar one taking place after the *harrying of the north*:

   > For around two centuries after the establishment of Norman rule in England, English was spoken but relatively seldom written. Even so, the influence of English continued to spread. Although Scotland was a separate kingdom, King David, the heir of Malcolm and Margaret, established peaceful relations with many powerful Norman barons, granting them land in the Scottish lowlands. These barons brought with them many English-speaking retainers, mainly from northern England, where there was a strong Norse influence. A distinct variety of the language, first known as ‘Inglis’ and much later as ‘Scottis’, evolved. Today, the pronunciation and vocabulary of the lowland Scots language is often very close to its Old English (OE) origins, as in ‘hoose’, ‘moose’ and ‘coo’ (OE hus, mus, cu)

This is consistent with a change occurring in Middle English.  I find other explanations of the Celtic substrate re-emerging less convincing because of the 5 century gap between the invasion of the Anglo Saxons and the Exeter Book.

**Online Resources**

- ["What is your name?" in more than 330 languages”](http://users.elite.net/runner/jennifers/yourname.htm).
- [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aMain_Page) for all the small words included in the Celtic part.
- [Brittonicisms in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brittonicisms_in_English).
- [Middle English creolisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_creole_hypothesis).

Comment: This is a really excellent answer. Thank you and thanks for the resources that will help me explore more on my own.

Comment: There's no really any "conclusivity" in this answer, and also to the question, unfortunately, as it's an interesting question. Too bad all people have sad so far is "I dunno" or maybe "We dunno."

Comment: How is it not conclusive?  They clearly gave their theory and backed it up.  Do you need the first person to ever say 'what is your name' in English to personally write down why they wrote it that way along with three forms of picture ID?  There isn't going to be a 100% certain answer to a question like this because linguistics is a soft science based on limited evidence sets.

Answer (score 6):

In older versions of English we used the verb *[hight](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hight)*: hight (ht) *adj*. *Archaic* Named or called.

It would be parallel to the German construction, *Er heisst Karl*: "He hight Wiliam."

> [Middle English, past participle of highten, hihten, to call, be called, from *hehte*, *hight*, past tense of *hoten*, from Old English *hatan*; see *kei-2* in Indo-European roots.]

This doesn't address your question involving "What is your name?" But it does show that English did have a more "universal" way to say how to call someone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that @Robusto.  I think it is a big help to me for trying to figure out when English picked up this phrase.

Comment: Not to mention [*"y-clept"*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yclept), also used in older versions of English.

Comment: @PeterShor: So it's not just quantum computers that are "reversing time" now, eh? ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it is really that different.

After all, the **name** is that by which something or someone is **called**, and the two phrases have the same meaning.

There are languages that follow one pattern or another (with variations, such as 'how do you call yourself?' and so on). Also, note swiss German might say: "Wie isch ire Name?"

From the etymology of [*call*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=call) we have a meaning "to give a name to" which is (from) mid-13c in English.

The word *name*, comes from Old English nama. Meaning "one's reputation" is from c.1300.

So, there seems to be a great overlap between the two phrases and the meanings. I don't know what determined one phrase as more adequate than the other (neither in English nor in other languages).

One theory could be that in medieval Europe, [bynames](http://www.s-gabriel.org/names/arval/bynames/) were used to identify people. As these are not hereditary nor given at time of birth maybe other languages made a distinction between a name (that is given or hereditary) and the way someone is actually called (bynames).

Still, if this theory holds it does not answer why in English the same principle would not apply.

Comment: I find your thought about bynames particularly interesting.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: And don't underestimate the value of demonstrating that both phrases come from the same or similar origins.  I am interested in how we got to where we are now, so it is good to know that at one time we had a construction that was similar to the others, but could easily have evolved into what we have now.

Answer (score 1):

Dutch uses the same construction.  My understanding is that Dutch, English, and German all have the same root, but that German has drifted grammatically the furthest from that root language.  Hence I would assume that the construction has its root in old Saxon or another old Germanic dialect/language that came over with the Saxons, Danes, or Norwegians that shares a common root with Dutch.

Having looked at the site (posted by another user above) at http://users.elite.net/runner/jennifers/yourname.htm, it looks like Danish shares the same construction as well.  I looked around further and, like Dutch, West Frisian has options for both constructions.

EDIT: Removed IIRC from the first sentence, which I wrote before viewing the link that confirms my recollection.

Also, because the above was not clear enough for some readers, I would posit that the construction in English has its roots in an older Germanic language, and has survived in several other Germanic languages, but not in German.

Comment: The link you provide shows both versions for Dutch. So really, unless you have some other knowledge than "IIRC" this answer is interesting but it's not really an answer (also, I don't think the accepted answer is conclusive). Your link also shows that Afrikaans has only the 'What is your name?' version....

Comment: The IIRC was from the semester of Dutch that I took, but it was five years ago and I have not used it in four.  I'm not sure how it is not an answer - two other Germanic languages, one of which is spoken in a region where the Germanic ancestors of the English people lived, have the same construction, whereas the other language that most heavily influenced English, Old French, does not.  While the other answer that suggests a Celtic origin may have some merit, Celtic has very little influence on English (besides a very limited set of loan words and etymologies), making a Germanic origin likely.

Comment: @Clare Can you explain why you downvoted?  Your comment doesn't really seem to suggest that the response was not an answer for any particular reason, or to refute it, so I'm a little confused.

English got it from an older Germanic root that has not survived in German but has survived in other Germanic languages that are closely related, both historically and linguistically, to English.